# Какие поля участвуют в сортировке при выборке из mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
 order by ((( currency = 'rub' ) * cost ) + ((currency = 'usd') * cost * 1 / 0.033) + ((currency = 'eur') * cost * 1 / 0.025) ) asc limit 0 , 10
```

Данная сортировка работает по стоимости товара (cost) с учетом выбранной валюты (currency )

Можете объяснить как это работает в моем случае, а то не пойму что на что умножается тут,а потом складывается?
Т.к для меня понятно только если бы было так  `order by cost asc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
имеем, грубо говоря 3 условия:
сделано по принципу(( 1 ) 2 ) - где 1 - проверка валюты, если она соответствует условию, то 
//будет 1, иначе 0, т.е. перемножаемое(2) с этим действием обнуляется(в нашем случае это 1-о из 3-х слагаемых)
    (( currency = 'rub' ) * cost ) // если ячейка столбца currency имеет значение 'rub'
//то просто сортируем по значению cost

//В этих двух случаях, если ячейка currency имеет значение 'eur' либо 'usd'
//то умножаем cost на повышающий коэффициент, т.е. грубо говоря, переводим в рубли.
    ((currency = 'usd') * cost * 1 / 0.033)
    ((currency = 'eur') * cost * 1 / 0.025)
```

Коротко говоря, эта выборка сортирует по цене, *в рублях*, не затрагивая при этом, цены позиций в валюте.

Answer (score 2):

Извращение над нестрогой системой приведения типов в mysql.

Сначала это выражение вычисляется для каждой строки результата, затем по этой цифре происходит сортировка. На сортировку влияют все поля, упомянутые в выражении, сортируются по результату выражения.

```
( currency = 'rub' )
```

Если поле currency строки равно строке 'rub', то будет получено true, иначе false. Затем попытка умножить на значение cost этой строки. Умножение - операция числовая, поэтому булев результат приводится к числу. Если было true - то к 1, false - к 0. И производится умножение. Если валюта совпала с 'rub', то результатом будет значение поля cost, иначе - 0.

Аналогично для других слагаемых:

```
((currency = 'usd') * cost * 1 / 0.033)
```

Если валюта была usd, то 1 умножается на cost и умножается на 1 и делится на 0.033. Если валюта не usd - то будет 0, т.к. умножение нуля на что угодно будет 0.

В итоге в каждом слагаемом проверяется валюта. Если валюта не совпала - то это слагаемое превращается в 0.

Более явным образом это можно записать как case:

```
case currency
  when 'rub' then cost
  when 'usd' then cost / 0.033
  when 'eur' then cost / 0.025
end
```

Comment: спасибо. Последний вопрос,а то немного не понял : страница сортировки по цене у меня 
`?sort=cost&tsort=asc`
Валюта тут не указывается . Получается, что данная конструкция не работает в данном запросе ?

Comment: Как может быть связан SQL и, судя по всему, query string - известно именно вам. Смотрите, как формируете SQL. Может быть вообще никакой взаимосвязи.

Answer (score 0):

Работает это очень просто. Если выражение сравнения в скобках истинно, оно равно единице, если нет - нулю. Само понимаешь, что только одна из трёх проверок вернёт единицу. Соответственно мы сложим для этой единицы стоимость, конвертированную соотв. коэффициентом в рубли, и два нуля, полученные умножением нуля из-за неравенства на коэффициенты для других двух валют. На выходе это даст стоимость в рублях, какая бы валюта не была. И по этой стоимости и сортируем. Всё в рублях, сортировка правильная.